# Is it cheating to change the random state for test-train split to get the best r2 score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, random-seed

I notice that my r2 score (for the test set) changes significantly when I play around with the random state for a linear regression model. The scores can change orders of magnitude - fluctuating between -10^4 to 0.97. While the performance is better, I can't help wondering if this is not cheating. After all, shouldn't a good model work for all selections of test and training data? By selecting a random state that works, aren't we really creating a model that works best for the given test data and may not work equally well for all data points in the future?

```
state=random.randint(0,100)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=state)
```

Comment: Yes, selecting the best fitting subset of your dataset that gives the most accurate result is probably one of the most extreme ways you can overfit on the data. Bad idea if you want to generalise. Also, I downvoted the question because I don't think this is a question for SO since it's not directly related to programming or implementation but is a general conceptual question and probably belong in AI stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Yes, it's cheating.**

Theoretically, you can't touch or adapt any parameter in order to increase your test accuracy.

Furthermore, what are you obtaining with this information is that your model is not quiet good, it depends a lot on the input data, that shouldn't happened, probably you are overfitting. Check the train accuracy and test accuracy, if they differ, probably your are overfitting.